# Put S3 file to FTP server using storbinary without downloading to a local temporary file using Lambda or Glue

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to put an S3 file to an FTP server using a Glue Python shell. Below given is the code. I am stuck after getting the file from S3. Tried few ways of `storbinary` but in vain. It is easy if we try from local using Python but since this is from Glue/Lambda, the file handling part is bit tricky.

```
import ftplib
import boto3
from io import BytesIO,StringIO
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect('xxx',yyy)
ftp.login('uname','passwd')
ftp.cwd('path')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file = s3.get_object(Bucket='my_bucket',Key='myfolder/myfile.txt')
data = file['Body'].read()
with open(data,"rb") as f:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR test12.txt',f)
```

After the line `file = s3.get_object(Bucket='my_bucket',Key='myfolder/myfile.txt')`, bit confused on the next steps.  Any help on how this can be done is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use something like `BytesIO`/`StringIO` file-like objects:

```
b = BytesIO(file['Body'].read())
ftp.storbinary('STOR test12.txt', b)
```

*(untested, just a concept)*